# Counting the number of pairs in a vector

Tags: r, count, duplicates, categories

Suppose that I have the following vector:

```
V<-c(-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1)
```

And I want to know the number of different pairs in the following categories:

(1,1), (-1,1), (1,-1), and (-1,-1)

In my example, there is exactly 1 pair of each.

I have been trying to solve this problem with the function `split` and `setkey`, but I can't do the categorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ng <- length(V)/2
table(sapply(split(V,rep(1:ng,each=2)),paste0,collapse="&"))
# -1&-1  -1&1  1&-1   1&1 
#     1     1     1     1
```

---

Here is a better alternative that also uses `split`, following the pattern of @MartinMorgan's answer:

```
table(split(V,1:2))
#     2
# 1    -1 1
#   -1  1 1
#   1   1 1
```

Comment: Actually, I think there is something that may not be working. I took a piece from my vector that  looks like this:  V<-c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1). When I use your code, I get the following results: The number of -1&-1 is 3 (and should be 4) and the number of (-1,1) is 2 (instead of 0), because the next pair is (1,1). Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You were right in saying that I want it to be done sequentially, that is, after evaluating the first pair, observations 1 and 2, go with 3 and 4, and so on. I think your code does something different by comparing non sequential observations.

Comment: @juanalbertoarroyomiranda Oh, sorry, I needed to write `each=2` in the `rep`. Now it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Create an index that will re-cycle to select the first (or when negated second) element

```
> idx = c(TRUE, FALSE)
```

Then cross-tabulate the occurrence of observations

```
> xtabs(~V[idx] + V[!idx])
      V[!idx]
V[idx] -1 1
    -1  1 1
    1   1 1
```

Comment: I think this is the best approach, though for nicer margin labels, I'd do `first <- V[c(TRUE,FALSE)]; second <- V[c(FALSE,TRUE)]; table(first,second)` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
table(apply(matrix(v, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE), 1, paste, collapse = ",") )
```

Comment: I was just posting a similar solution, so I''ll just leave this in comments `table(do.call(paste, as.data.frame(matrix(V, ncol = 2))))`

Comment: However, there is something that may  not be working. I think the code is not doing the categorization sequentially, that is, after evaluating the first pair, observations 1 and 2, go with 3 and 4, and so on. Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: well ... I think it does. The vector is formated as a two column matrix with 1,2 in the first row, 3, 4 in the second... Make sure you use `byrow = TRUE` in the matrix function