# Count the number of consecutive pairs in a vector

Tags: r, split, count, categories

Suppose that I have the following vector:

```
    V<-c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1)
```

and I want to count the number of CONSECUTIVE pairs in the following categories:

```
    (1,1), (-1,1), (1,-1), and (-1,-1).
```

In my example, there are seven consecutive pairs of `(-1,-1)`, one pair of `(-1,1)`, and 1 pair of `(1,1)`.

I am trying to solve this problem using the split function, but I have not been able to figure out the correct factors.

The idea is to pair the 1st observation with the 2nd. The 2nd with the 3rd and so on. The final pair should be the (n-1)th observation with the nth observation.

Comment: Not quite the same as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30489952/980833)

Comment: May be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643798/counting-consecutive-numbers-in-a-vector-or-array-in-r  ?

Comment: Can we take it that you never have more than two possible values in your vector?

Comment: Yes, my vector only has 1's and -1's

Comment: I think the emphasis on "consecutive" is confusing here, since it sounds like you're talking about "runs." See, for example, `?rle` for what I mean by that term.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All consecutive pairs can be represented by two parallel vectors, omitting the last or the first observation

```
x <- V[-length(V)]
y <- V[-1]
```

and then cross-tabulating these

```
> xtabs(~ x + y)
    y
x    -1 1
  -1  7 1
  1   0 1
```

or in slightly different form

```
> as.data.frame(xtabs(~x+y))
   x  y Freq
1 -1 -1    7
2  1 -1    0
3 -1  1    1
4  1  1    1
```

Answer (score 9):

Maybe something like that

```
library(zoo)
table(rollapply(V, 2, toString))
# -1, -1  -1, 1   1, 1 
#      7      1      1
```

Or with base R

```
table(paste(head(V, -1), tail(V, -1)))
# -1 -1  -1 1   1 1 
#     7     1     1
```

Or as per @akruns comment, without `paste`

```
table(head(V, -1), tail(V, -1))
#    -1 1
# -1  7 1
#  1  0 1
```

Or

```
as.data.frame(table(head(V, -1), tail(V, -1)))
#   Var1 Var2 Freq
# 1   -1   -1    7
# 2    1   -1    0
# 3   -1    1    1
# 4    1    1    1
```

Comment: Can't quite tell: it looks like the first way works for N different values in the input but the second may not.  Can you check?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft not quite following. Can you provide an example? I've tested on `V<-sample(1:3, 15, replace = TRUE)`, for example and everything seems to be fine.

Comment: maybe `V <-  sample(1:5, 100, replace=TRUE)` so that there are 25 possible `Vj,Vj+1` pairs.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that works fine for your vector. I think you are confused because `toString` adds a comma while `paste` isn't

Comment: Deleting the paste option would give the crosstabulation `table(head(V, -1), tail(V, -1))`

Answer (score 7):

With **data.table**:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- rev(data.table(embed(V,2)))
dt[,.N, by=names(dt)]
#    V2 V1 N
# 1: -1 -1 7
# 2: -1  1 1
# 3:  1  1 1
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R, add the right half of the pair to the difference to create a score:

```
V<-c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1)
table(diff(V) + V[-1])    
#-1  1  3 
# 7  1  1
```

This is how each pair is scored:

```
(-1,-1) => (-1) - (-1) + (-1) = -1
(-1, 1) => ( 1) - (-1) +  (1) =  3
( 1,-1) => (-1) -  (1) + (-1) = -3
( 1, 1) => ( 1) -  (1) +  (1) =  1
```